# How to send hashtage with meassage text of Telegram bot api

Tags: python, telegram, py-telegram-bot-api

i want sell hastage with telegram bot api as below

```
url = r.post(url=f"https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=233331114&text= Binance Future \U0001F3E6  #BTC/USDT \nEntry achived    {1471} \U0001F4B0")
```

So the issue is I recived just that message in my channel

```
Binance Future
```

all text after # is disapeard

Comment: Hi! Have you tried something like this - `text_var = f' Binance Future \U0001F3E6  #BTC/USDT \nEntry achived    {1471} \U0001F4B0' url = r.post(url=f"https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage?chat_id=233331114&text={text_var}")`?

Comment: @pugi thanks for your answer 
i tried your way but nothing changed

Comment: Have you tried `url = https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage text_var = f' Binance Future \U0001F3E6  #BTC/USDT \nEntry achived    {1471} \U0001F4B0' my_data = {"chat_id": 233331114, "text":text_var} response = r.post(url, data=my_data)`

Comment: yes thats work thanks aloooooooot

Comment: great I'll change this into an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in my comment, this should work:

```
url = https://api.telegram.org/bot/sendMessage
text_var = f' Binance Future \U0001F3E6  #BTC/USDT \nEntry achived    {1471} \U0001F4B0' 
my_data = {"chat_id": 233331114, "text":text_var} 
response = r.post(url, data=my_data)
```